# Biblatex bibliography not sorted alphabetically in Lyx

Tags: biblatex, lyx, jabref

I am using Lyx to write my Master's thesis this spring semester. I am using Paper (Standard Class) as my document class and have a Biblatex .bib bibliography database that I'm continuously updating through JabRef. I have not added anything to the LaTeX Preamble as I'm using the functions built into Lyx to change the properties of the document. These are the settings I use for the Bibliography (I have also tried with the standard Biblatex style format with the same result).

[image]

The problem is that in the output file, the references are not listed in alphabetical order. It's not even in order of appearance but seems to be in the order I added them to the text. See output below.

[image]

I have tried to search for an answer, but as far as I have learned, alphabetical is the "standard" order and as I haven't made any changes to the Bibliography style that would be what I expect to happen. Sorry if it's something that has already been answered or if it's super basic (I am a complete novice) - grateful for any help.

Thank you,
Claes

EDIT: as requested, here is the .tex file (not my actual thesis file but I was able to reproduce it. I changed document class to Article (Standard Class) as per instructions of how to create a MWF):

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{natbib=true}{biblatex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{uppsats/masterthesis.bib}
\begin{document}
Text A \citep{Herzig2006} then Text B \citep{Rahm2016} then Text
C \citep{Alvesson2019} then Text D \citep{Meyer1997} then Text E
\citep{DiMaggio1983}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Output looks like this:

[image]

And a sample from the .bib file:

```
    @Article{Meyer1997,
    author  = {John W. Meyer and Brian Rowan},
  title   = {Institutionalized Organizations: Formal Structure as Myth and Ceremony},
  journal = {American Journal of Sociology},
  year    = {1977},
  volume  = {83},
  number  = {2},
  url     = {https://doi.org/10.1086/226550},
  urldate = {2021-02-27},
}

@Article{DiMaggio1983,
  author  = {Paul J. DiMaggio and Walter W. Powell},
  title   = {The Iron Cage Revisited: Institutional Isomorphism and Collective Rationality in Organizational Fields},
  journal = {American Sociological Review},
  year    = {1983},
  volume  = {48},
  number  = {2},
  url     = {https://doi.org/10.2307/2095101},
  urldate = {2021-02-28},
}

@InBook{Herzig2006,
  author    = {Christian Herzig and Stefan Schaltegger},
  title     = {Corporate Sustainability Reporting: An Overview},
  booktitle = {Sustainability Accounting and Reporting},
  year      = {2006},
  editor    = {Stefan Schaltegger and Martin Bennett and Roger Burritt},
  publisher = {Springer},
  location  = {Dordrecht},
  chapter   = {13},
  pages     = {301-324},
  url       = {https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4020-4974-3_1},
  urldate   = {2021-02-28},
}

@Article{Alvesson2019,
  author  = {Mats Alvesson and Andre Spicer},
  title   = {Neo-Institutional Theory and Organization Studies: A Mid-Life Crisis?},
  journal = {Organization Studies},
  year    = {2019},
  volume  = {40},
  number  = {2},
  pages   = {199-218},
  url     = {https://doi.org/10.1177%2F0170840618772610},
  urldate = {2021-03-01},
}
```

EDIT 2: Thank you very much for taking the time to check my issue. I do not have support for Biber in my version of Lyx, it seems, which is strange as I have version 2.3.6.1 installed and from version 2.3, Lyx should have native Biber support from what I have been able to find. I am on Ubuntu now but will soon be switching to Mac OS so I will have to wait and see if the issue is resolved with a new installation of Lyx on Mac. Will update and hopefully close this question if and when it is resolved. /Claes

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: This doesn't look right. Can you share the `.bib` file with us? Would it be possible to export the `.tex` file and paste it to the question so we can have a look at the code? Please create a minimal example: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge) so you can regain control over you post.

Comment: Thank you for posting an MWE. I ran your code and could not reproduce the incorrect sort order. I got the expected order (Alvesson > DiMaggio > Herzig > Meyer). I notice that your document is compiled with BibTeX8. Nowadays one should be using Biber. There is no guarantee that this will work, but you should definitely try to change the "Processor" under Document > Settings > Bibliography > Bibliography Generation from "Default" to "Biber".